# joint_state_controller required for diff_drive_controller?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is `joint_state_controller` required when working with `diff_drive_controller`?  Or is `joint_state_controller` only required to publish `JointState` messages for other nodes and not relevant for `diff_drive_controller` to function properly?

For example [eborghi10/my_ROS_mobile_robot](https://github.com/eborghi10/my_ROS_mobile_robot/tree/e04acfd3e7eb4584ba0aab8a969a74d6c30eed34/my_robot_control/config) uses two yaml config files, [one](https://github.com/eborghi10/my_ROS_mobile_robot/blob/master/my_robot_control/config/my_robot_common.yaml) containing `diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController` as expected and [the other one](https://github.com/eborghi10/my_ROS_mobile_robot/blob/master/my_robot_control/config/my_robot_control.yaml) contains `joint_state_controller/JointStateController` and even `effort_controllers/JointEffortController`. Are these controllers really required?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346049/joint_state_controller-required-for-diff_drive_controller?/) by [fjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/9816/fjp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2020-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

> Is joint_state_controller required when working with diff_drive_controller?

Technically if you talk in terms of simulation with Gazebo, joint states are published by ros_gazebo_diff_drive plugin and we do not require a separate joint state controller. You can just verify it by launching the ROS node for the same and looking into the rqt_graph. They basically use the model states from the gazebo to perform the calculation for the kinematics. If I remember correctly!

> For example eborghi10/my_ROS_mobile_robot uses two yaml config files, one containing diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController as expected and the other one contains joint_state_controller/JointStateController and even effort_controllers/JointEffortController. Are these controllers really required?

If you see the code from [gazebo_diff_drive_controller](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/25e881baeb2152482a66c31f1effaa32ced64f8e/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_diff_drive.cpp#L159) they already publish the joint states!

I don't think,we need a joint effort controller for the diff drive robot ! Just if it is only the velocity!

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 224 on 2020-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/9816/fjp/) on 2020-03-06**:
Thank you for your answer! Could you please explain what you mean with the following

> You can just verify it by launching the ROS node for the same and looking into the rqt_graph. They basically use the model states from the gazebo to perform the calculation for the kinematics.

Do you mean launching joint_state_controller and the ros_gazebo_diff_drive plugin will publish JointState twice (via each of the two nodes)? And do you know where in the code the published model states (joint states) are used?

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2020-03-06**:
Just launch the node with the ros_gazebo_diff_plugin and you can see that the joint states are already published!

**Comment by [fjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/9816/fjp/) on 2020-03-06**:
Do we need a joint_state_controller when working with real robot hardware?

**Comment by [fjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/9816/fjp/) on 2020-03-06**:
Thanks for your help so far! Another question about your answer I have is what do you mean by

> Just if it is only the velocity!